# Easiest way to make multi-page images in Microsoft Word?

Tags: images, microsoft-word

If you have a number of images that are too large to fit on one page in a Microsoft Word document - is there an easier way to embed them into the document than splitting them with an image editor? The width of the images fits on the page, but they are often 2-3 pages high.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paste them into multiple pages and crop them.

Crop each one from the top by a multiple of the (visible) page length, so crop the second one by (say) 27 cm, the third by 54, etc.
You don't say which version of Word you have, but the options for specific crop measurement are in the "size" dialog for the picture (rather than doing this by hand)

Comment: Just make sure you tell MS word to compress images after doing this otherwise the cropped parts of the image will remain in the document, making the file size quite large.

Answer (score 8):

If you need to just print this document, you can do this by pasting into Excel. Lines will appear that will show you where the split occurs. I use this when people send me long images.